# SQL Server, Having Clause, Where, Aggregate Functions

Tags: sql-server, function, aggregate, where-clause, having

In my problem which I am trying to solve, there is a performance values table:

```
Staff       PerformanceID   Date        Percentage
--------------------------------------------------
StaffName1  1               2/15/2016   95
StaffName1  2               2/15/2016   95
StaffName1  1               2/22/2016   100
...
StaffName2  1               2/15/2016   100
StaffName2  2               2/15/2016   100
StaffName2  1               2/22/2016   100
```

And the SQL statement as follows:

```
SELECT TOP (10)     
    tbl_Staff.StaffName, 
    ROUND(AVG(tbl_StaffPerformancesValues.Percentage), 0) AS AverageRating
FROM                
    tbl_Staff 
INNER JOIN
    tbl_AcademicTermsStaff ON tbl_Staff.StaffID = tbl_AcademicTermsStaff.StaffID 
INNER JOIN
    tbl_StaffPerformancesValues ON tbl_AcademicTermsStaff.StaffID = tbl_StaffPerformancesValues.StaffID
WHERE
    (tbl_StaffPerformancesValues.Date >= @DateFrom) 
    AND (tbl_AcademicTermsStaff.SchoolCode = @SchoolCode) 
    AND (tbl_AcademicTermsStaff.AcademicTermID = @AcademicTermID)
GROUP BY            
    tbl_Staff.StaffName
ORDER BY            
    AverageRating DESC, tbl_Staff.StaffName
```

What I am trying to do is, from a given date, for instance 02-22-2016, 
I want to calculate average performance for each staff member.

The code above gives me average without considering the date filter.

Thank you.

Comment: Your code has `WHERE tbl_StaffPerformancesValues.Date >= @DateFrom`. Doesn't that apply a date filter? Please clarify

Comment: or should it be a EQUAL condition ? 'tbl_StaffPerformancesValues.Date = @DateFrom'

Comment: what is the data type for Percentage ? If it is integer, AVG ( ) it will give you result in integer only. So the ROUND() has no effect actually

Comment: Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies, the code above, as you all say and as it is also expected is correct.

I intended to have a date filter to see the results from the given date until now.

The code

```
WHERE tbl_StaffPerformancesValues.Date >= @DateFrom
```

is correct.

The mistake i found from my coding is, in another block i had the following:

```
Protected Sub TextBoxDateFrom_Text(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBoxDate.PreRender, TextBoxDate.TextChanged
        Try

            Dim strDate As String = Date.Parse(DatesOfWeekISO8601(2016, WeekOfYearISO8601(Date.Today))).AddDays(-7).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

            If Not IsPostBack Then
                TextBoxDate.Text = strDate
            End If

            SqlDataSourcePerformances.SelectParameters("DateFrom").DefaultValue = Date.Parse(TextBoxDate.Text, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("id-ID")).AddDays(-7)

            GridViewPerformances.DataBind()

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
End Sub
```

I, unintentionally, applied `.AddDays(-7)` twice. 
I just noticed it and removed the second `.AddDays(-7)` from my code.

```
SqlDataSourcePerformances.SelectParameters("DateFrom").DefaultValue = Date.Parse(TextBoxDate.Text, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("id-ID"))
```

Because of that mistake, the SQL code was getting the performance values 14 days before until now. So the average was wrong.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from your join conditions and table names which looks quite complex, One simple question, If you want the results for a particular date then why is the need of having

`WHERE tbl_StaffPerformancesValues.Date >= @DateFrom`

As you said your query is displaying average results but not for a date instance. Change the above line to `WHERE tbl_StaffPerformancesValues.Date = @DateFrom`.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.